# SonataAdminBundle: Create custom filter type

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Is there a way to create a custom filter type for SonataAdminBundle, that extends another type, for example the type doctrine_orm_callback? The idea is for re-use the custom type in other filters

```
public function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{

    $datagridMapper
        ->add('field', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
            'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                if (!$value['value']) {
                    return;
                }

                $queryBuilder->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.field', $alias), 'field')
                    ->andWhere("field LIKE :field")
                    ->setParameter('field', "%{$value['value']}%");

                return true;
            },
            'field_type' => 'search'), null, array('pattern' => '^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,12}$'));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Define function in AdminService and function invoque :p

Comment: I have created a custom filter [*`Sonata-admin-number-range-filter`*](https://github.com/dianuj89/Sonata-admin-number-range-filter) a time ago hope this will give you an idea to proceed for your solution

Answer (score 2):

Check this [link](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/2-0/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html#callback) and try:

```
->add('with_open_comments', 
      'doctrine_orm_callback', 
      array('callback'   => array($this, 'yourFunction'),
            'field_type' => 'search'), 
      null, 
      array('pattern' => '^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,12}$'));

    public function yourFunction($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value)
    {
        if (!$value['value']) {
           return;
        }

        $queryBuilder->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.field', $alias), 'field')
                    ->andWhere("field LIKE :field")
                    ->setParameter('field', "%{$value['value']}%");

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Again.. Define function in AdminService and function invoque :p